# Как корректно заменить в pandas '0.24.2': -np.inf и отдельно np.inf на числа?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

Как корректно заменить в pandas '0.24.2': -np.inf на -9999, а np.inf на 9999?
df.replace никак не выручает, а точнее не видит в таблице ни inf, ни -inf ?

пока обхожусь таким решением:

```
train[features] = train[features].fillna(-999) #замена nan на -999
pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True
train[features] = train[features].fillna(-9999) #замена -inf и inf на -9999
```

но здесь замена двух бесконечностей на одно число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
     a    b
0 -inf  2.0
1  3.0  inf
2  inf -inf
```

Решение:

```
In [36]: df = df.replace([-np.inf, np.inf], [-9999, 9999])
```

Результат:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
        a       b
0 -9999.0     2.0
1     3.0  9999.0
2  9999.0 -9999.0
```

Comment: Работает! спасибо, Максим, что аппелировали)) train[features] = train[features].replace([-np.inf, np.inf], [-9999, 9999])

Comment: Дай бог здоровья людям, которые бескорыстно выручают! Я не только про помощь в этом тикете, а вообще) у меня у самого сервис краудсорсинговой помощи по музыке: hazanda.com - но времени на развитие нет свободного)

Comment: кстати ошибка была когда меняем на 99999, а не 9999

Comment: @AlexandrKosolapov, всегда рад помочь) Не думаю что поведение изменится если менять на 99999 вместо 9999...

Comment: у меня ругался RFclassifier, который внутри боруты был))